# Writing a plugin to open a new file

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

In Sublime Text 3 I have a few packages that open new files within the window. They have functions that look like:

```
class BufferCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        view = self.window.new_file()
        ...
```

I grabbed this for something I am working on, and couldn't get a new file to generate, even though that works for the plugin I snagged it from, and is similar to how it is used in `Packages/Default/new_templates.py`. After some more searching, I found the following code, and it works as expected

```
class TestCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self,edit):
       view = self.view.window().new_file()
```

Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Noted you're subclassing from different classes?

Comment: @cdonts I assume you mean the `TextCommand`? If so, yes I noticed that too. By changing it to `WindowCommand`, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It might be the way you are running your command? If you are entering

```
    view.run_command("buffer")
```

into the python console, then nothing will happen if BufferCommand is not a TextCommand.

Instead try this:

```
    window.run_command("buffer")
```

This should fix your problem.